# Unable to close modal window via FontAwesome Icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some trouble closing out a modal window with the controller that I've setup. Currently I can open the modal but I'm unable to get it to close. I am using AngularJS to do this, no bootstrap at all.

**Js file:**

```
$scope.closeMenu=false;
$scope.showMenu=false;
$scope.showItems=false;
$scope.modalFunc= function(){
   $scope.showMenu = !$scope.showMenu;
   console.log($scope.selected);
   $scope.showItems = !$scope.showItems;
   $scope.closeMenu=!$scope.closeMenu;
};
```

**Html file:**

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-repeat="album in albums" ng-click="setActive(album)" ng-hide="showItems">
    <p ng-click="modalFunc()"><i class="expand fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <ul class="hide">
      <li class="desc">{{album.artist}}</li>
      <li class="desc">{{album.title}}</li>
      <li class="desc">$1.29</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#text">
      <img src={{album.img}}>
    </a>
    <button ng-click="setActive(album); cartFunc()" id="{{album.id}}"><a>Add</a></button>
  </div>
  <section class="modal" ng-show="showMenu">
    <div ng-click="setActive(album)">
      <p ng-click="modalFunc()" class="exit"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      <h1>{{albumMod.artist}} - {{albumMod.title}}</h1>
      <ul class="tracks">
        <span><img src={{albumMod.img}}></span>
        <li>Album: {{albumMod.album}}</li>
        <li>Price: $1.29</li>
      </ul>
      <form style="display: inline" action="/#cart" method="get">
        <button ng-click="setActive(album); cartFunc()" id="{{album.id}}"><a>Add</a></button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `modalFunc` ? Unclear from the code you pasted how you expect the modal to close.

Comment: I have the modalFunc running above this code in another div to show a button that activates the modal.   I've updated the code above.

Comment: I also have it running in the <p> element as well

Comment: Would probably need a jsfiddle, there are many things that can go wrong here, like scoping issues.

Comment: It's most likely a scoping issue.  Here's a JSFiddle.  Hope it helps, also thanks for taking a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/travis_johnson/jp584vLo/

Comment: The jsfiddle have a lot of errors. Here's a plnkr working: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y46dZ3s8FHZ6ie5aSG0o?p=preview, can you let there only the relevant code?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @developer033, unfortunately after applying my css into the plunker, it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Copy here the link of updated plnkr.

Comment: @developer033 :  http://plnkr.co/edit/xCPt867W3Bq5dt75uUMo?p=preview

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not use http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/modals? I think you could save a good time.

Comment: @developer033 , too far into the project and approaching deadline to switch things up to Angular-Strap.